# Blank Cell not in xls convert to csv using perl

Tags: excel, perl, csv

I have below script that covert xls to csv ok but it does not convert blank cell in my xls to blanks in csv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $sourcename = shift @ARGV or die "invocation: $0 <source file>\n";
my $source_excel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $source_book = $source_excel->Parse($sourcename) 
    or die "Could not open source Excel file $sourcename: $!";
my $storage_book;

foreach my $source_sheet_number (0 .. $source_book->{SheetCount}-1) {
 my $source_sheet = $source_book->{Worksheet}[$source_sheet_number];

 print "--------- SHEET:", $source_sheet->{Name}, "\n";
 next unless defined $source_sheet->{MaxRow};
 next unless $source_sheet->{MinRow} <= $source_sheet->{MaxRow};
 next unless defined $source_sheet->{MaxCol};
 next unless $source_sheet->{MinCol} <= $source_sheet->{MaxCol};

 foreach my $row_index ($source_sheet->{MinRow} .. $source_sheet->{MaxRow}) {
  foreach my $col_index ($source_sheet->{MinCol} .. $source_sheet->{MaxCol}) {
   my $source_cell = $source_sheet->{Cells}[$row_index][$col_index];
   if ($source_cell) {
   #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
   print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   }
  }
  print "\n";
 }
}
```

sample excel

```
ABC BCC DCC DES
SDE     KOT FET
```

it converts as

```
ABC;BCC;DCC;DES;
SDE;KOT;FET;
```

instead of

```
ABC;BCC;DCC;DES;
SDE;;KOT;FET;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to create a CSV then please use Text::CSV, it is going to save you a lot of headache.

'if $source' code does not going to match for empty cells.

Fix for your code:

```
   if (defined $source_cell) {
     #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
     print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   } else {
     print ';';
   }
```